# escape single quotes inside onclick method JSP generated text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, onclick

I have the following link  
`<a href="#editModal" class="modal-with-form fa fa-edit" onclick="createEditPanel('/notes', '${note.getRequiredInfoFieldValue('note-title')}', '${note.getRequiredInfoFieldValue('note-title')}', ${note.getRequiredInfoFieldValue('note-text')});"></a>`

`${note.getRequiredInfoFieldValue('note-text')}` will sometimes have single quotes or double quotes in the text causing errors.
I need to be able to escape the text.

I have the following 
`<script>
 var text = '${note.getRequiredInfoFieldValue('note-text')}';
text = text.replace(/\"/g,'\\"');
</script>`

which works in escaping the characters but simply putting the text variable into the method does't work. It is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use

   ${fn:replace(note.getRequiredInfoFieldValue('note-text'), /\"/g,'\"')}

   inside onclick directly.

So that it will replace the single or double quotes with a escape sequence character.

Obviously you need to import jstl lib using:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix = "fn" %>
```

2. Use

`<c:out value="${note.getRequiredInfoFieldValue('note-text')}"/>` directly inside onclick.

3. `Use ${fn:escapeXml(note.getRequiredInfoFieldValue('note-text'))}`

Third approach is most recommended because you need not to put manual efforts to escape particular symbols.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up applying the fix in the java backend instead to prevent the need for JSP.